# JScript: How to get elevated privileges (admin rights)

Tags: jscript, wsh, elevated-privileges

Writing to certain folders and sections of the registry is only possible if a program runs elevated. Since you can't give JScript files a manifest that tells the OS which privileges the application wants, the question is do you work around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to check if you are running elevated on every start of the script and if you are not, then start a new instance of the script elevated and terminate the old instance.

```
EnsureElevatedPrivileges();
WScript.Echo("Running elevated now!");

function EnsureElevatedPrivileges() {
    if (!WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate")) {
        new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(WScript.FullName, "\"" + WScript.ScriptFullName + "\" /elevate", "", "runas", 1);
        WScript.Quit();
    }
}
```